# Using lombok dependency in my spring-boot project but the getter method yields error at runtime (built successfully though)

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-plugin, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am developing a spring-boot project using Gradle as the build tool on ItelliJ IDE.

I have the dependency of `lombok` declared in gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```

I have a model class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
public class ProductModel {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

As you can see I have annotated with `@Data`.

My controller has the method to handle a `POST` request, its payload is mapped to the `ProductModel`:

```
@PostMapping
public String createProduct(@RequestBody ProductModel productPayload) {
       // Runtime error: error: cannot find symbol, 'getName' in 'ProductModel'
       productPayload.getName();
}
```

I know I need to install the lombok plugin on my IntelliJ IDE in order to avoid compiler error on the getter method. So I did that.  But when I run my application I get error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getName()
location: variable productPayload of type CreateProductRestModel
```

I also tried change the dependency from `compileOnly` to `implementation`:

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
```

It doesn't help. Why is that? What am I missing?

(I have enabled `annotationProcessor` on my IntelliJ too)

Comment: have you only installed the plugin or also activated annotation processing? also there are `annotationProcessor` and `testAnnotationProcessor` dependencies in gradle which should be set.

Comment: I forget to mention that I have enabled annotationProcessor in IntelliJ. Could you please provide code snippet for the `annotationProcessor` in gradle?

Comment: Here you go https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: @thinkgruen could you please make an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Gradle to pick up on annotation processors, they have introduced a separate configuration that will generate all the new code ahead of the "normal" compilation.

For Lombok, it would look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```